# Change an element type, but keep the class attribute and text content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace my tag element without lost the class. For example, I would like to replace all my `<span class="vc_tta-tab.vc_active">` with `<h2 class="vc_tta-tab.vc_active">`

I'm using this script but it change only the first child and don't keep the class.

```js
  function replaceElement(source, newType) {
    // Create the document fragment
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Fill it with what's in the source element
    while (source.firstChild) {
      frag.appendChild(source.firstChild);
    }
    
    // Create the new element
    const newElem = document.createElement(newType);
    // Empty the document fragment into it
    newElem.appendChild(frag);

    // Replace the source element with the new element on the page
    source.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, source);
  }
 
  // Replace the <span> with a <h2>
  replaceElement(document.querySelector('span.vc_tta-title-text'), 'h2');
```

```html
<div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
<li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1570001325623-19515f51-28e7" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">CONTRIBUTI E BORSE DI STUDIO</span></a></li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1570001325641-ed1b27e5-545c" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">BORSE DI STUDIO ITACA INPS</span></a></li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1570001476621-8f5ad27d-ca8a" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">PROTEZIONE ANNULLAMENTO</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<style>
h2 {color:red;}
</style>
```

Can you help me to use a script to replace all my selector with all child?

Comment: What is stopping you, what errors are you getting ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I'm not sure what the point of your comment is. The OP has shown all relevant code, and described the issue and their goal. There is no error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Sir I wanted to say that, if he has tried that code so far, what is the output he's getting? Is there anything that is not working ? So that we can directly jump over it and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in jQuery by providing a function to `replaceWith()` that returns the new `<h2>` element to insert in to the DOM. Try this:

```js
$('span.vc_tta-title-text').replaceWith(function() {
  return `<h2 class="vc_tta-title-text">${$(this).text()}</h2>`;
});
```

```css
h2 { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
  <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325623-19515f51-28e7" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">CONTRIBUTI E BORSE DI STUDIO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325641-ed1b27e5-545c" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">BORSE DI STUDIO ITACA INPS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001476621-8f5ad27d-ca8a" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">PROTEZIONE ANNULLAMENTO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the same approach in plain JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.vc_tta-title-text').forEach(function(el) {
  var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  h2.textContent = el.textContent;
  h2.className = el.className;
  el.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', h2);
  el.remove();
});
```

```css
h2 { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
  <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325623-19515f51-28e7" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">CONTRIBUTI E BORSE DI STUDIO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325641-ed1b27e5-545c" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">BORSE DI STUDIO ITACA INPS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001476621-8f5ad27d-ca8a" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">PROTEZIONE ANNULLAMENTO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. 

Exist a way to do it without jquery? 

Because there is a conflicts with jquery and my other scripts.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a Javascript version, although I'm confused why you tagged the question with jQuery if you can't use it.

Comment: Thank you so much Rory.

It's perfect now.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change to @Rory code [Dynamically fetch & add class to span element]

```js
$('span.vc_tta-title-text').replaceWith(function(index, text, e) {
   return `<h2 class="${this.className}">${$(this).text()}</h2>`
});
```

```css
h2 { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
  <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325623-19515f51-28e7" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">CONTRIBUTI E BORSE DI STUDIO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001325641-ed1b27e5-545c" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">BORSE DI STUDIO ITACA INPS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#1570001476621-8f5ad27d-ca8a" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
        <span class="vc_tta-title-text hh">PROTEZIONE ANNULLAMENTO</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```